# Django - Multiple forms with different submit buttons not working

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to add a contact form and a login form on the same page but when entering the login information to the right form and then click on the submit button triggers the `this field is required` from the contact form mandatory fields.

I'm using Django 2.1 and postgreSQL.

My View:

```
def landing_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        contact_form = ContactForm()
        login_form = CustomAuthForm(request.POST)
    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        login_form = CustomAuthForm(request.POST)
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'contact_form':
            if contact_form.is_valid():
                name = contact_form.cleaned_data['name']
                phone = contact_form.cleaned_data['phone']
                from_email = contact_form.cleaned_data['from_email']
                message = contact_form.cleaned_data['message']
                subject = name + " Contact Beta Landing"
                msg = "\n \n Mail: " + str(from_email) + \
                      "\n \n Phone: " + str(phone) + \
                      "\n \n Message: \n \n" + message
                from_send_mail = "'\"" + \
                                 name + \
                                 "\" <contactBeta@ekiter.com>'"
                try:
                    send_mail(
                        subject,
                        msg,
                        from_send_mail,
                        ['contact@ekiter.com'])
                except BadHeaderError:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                     'Success! Thank you for your message, we will contact you.')
                return redirect('landing')
        elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'login_form':
            if login_form.is_valid():
                username = login_form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        return redirect('home')
                    else:
                        return redirect('landing')

    return render(request, "../templates/landing.html", {'form': contact_form, 'loginForm': login_form})
```

This is the contact form code:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.from_email|as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.phone|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {{ form.message|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit"
                    name="submit" value="contact_form">
                Send Message
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the Login form:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ loginForm.media }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {{ loginForm.username|as_crispy_field }}
            {{ loginForm.password|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" type="submit"
                    name="submit" value="login_form">
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Forms.py:
I add this just in case you want to check if there could be something wrong with it, but I can asure that both of them are working. The problem y trying to put both of them on the same page.

```
class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'validate', 'placeholder': 'User *'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password *'}))
```

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    phone = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # there's a `fields` property now
        self.fields['from_email'].required = True
        self.fields['name'].required = True
        self.fields['phone'].required = False
        self.fields['message'].required = True
        self.fields['from_email'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email *'})
        self.fields['name'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'maxlength': '40',
                   'placeholder': 'Your Name *'})
        self.fields['phone'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'maxlength': '15',
                   'placeholder': 'Your Phone (Optional)'})
        self.fields['message'].widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'rows': '2',
                   'maxlength': '5000',
                   'class': 'textarea-limited',
                   'placeholder': 'Your Message *'})
        # evade all labels and help text to appear when using "as_crispy_tag"
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper._help_text_inline = True
```

I think that the problem is on the view, but I don't know how to solve it. I tried to apply every related question on StackOverFlow but I couldn't solve it. I typically use the predefined Django Views, and this is my first "complex" request view.

With this code the contact form works perfectly (I accept better structural ways of sending a mail), the problem is, as I said at the beginning of this question, when I fill the login form.

Thank you in advice.

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the problem, but why is there no `action="url"`  in forms?

Comment: Doesn't look like you have closed the first form with </form>. Check this in your code or it is just a typo while posting here..

Comment: @Meryem I don't know, I started my project few months ago (from how django works) and every tutorial I followed didn't have the `action="url"` on forms, but is true that on django docs it appears. I didn't use it on any form on my page, but now I'm starting to think that I should... can you help me with this examples, please?
Until now all forms are working without problems, but is true that I only have one form per page...

Comment: @Lag11 sorry, a typo when copy&pasting. Edited.

Comment: try this way `<form method="post" action="{% url 'landing_view(or whatever your link is)' %}">`. and use `else` instead `elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'login_form':`. it is wrong to use elif without else

Comment: @Meryem okay, I added the action on both forms like `action="{% url 'landing' %}"` on contact form and  `action="{% url 'home' %}"` on login form. Now I get an error 405 when going through the login form (if the user is correct, wrong or invented), but the url changes always to the 'home' url. The error message on the debugger is:
```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /platform-home
Method Not Allowed: /platform-home
[17/Jul/2019 06:59:42] "POST /platform-home HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```
The contact form still going well.

Comment: I also checked with debug that putting another url to the login form works well but it doesn't go through the view. It just skips the view

Comment: you should put `action="{% url 'landing' %}"` on login form too, because the code will be processed there.  don't forget to change `elif`part and try this

Comment: I changed the elif, yes. Now I tried with both with landing url but still having the same problem as I had initially. When I enter the login form the fields on contact form triggers the empty field error.

Comment: Realising how this works I could just put `action="{% url 'login' %}"` on the login form and worked as expected. But this is just a work around. I would like to be able to manage multiple forms through the same view. (to let you know about this case)

Comment: I think the best approach is to process the two forms in different functions and urls on views.py

Comment: Okay! I’ll do that. Thank you very much! If you want to sum up your comments as an answer i’ll close the question with your valid answer :)